# Calculate refresh rate based on number of items

Tags: user-interface, page-refresh, rate

I have a system that produces *entries* at a variable rate. It could be 1 per second or 100 per second (or more, or less).

Then I have a page that needs to display about X items (let's say 10) on every screen refresh.

So, for example, if the system is producing 1 item per second, the best refresh rate to fetch items is 10 seconds.

What I need is a way to calculate the *next* best rate based on previous data, so on the next refresh I get a number of items that's about the number I'm looking for.

Of course this will not be perfect (if there are bursts of information I would probably retrieve much more items that the original 10) but that's not important.

The idea is to not over-fetch data (because showing one or two entries at a time is not productive), but also not let the system sleep for a long time, because 100 entries at a time are neither useful.

Any ideas on any algorithm to help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You already have your algorithm, your post describes it well.

If there is no previous data on the rate, then...
count the amount of items you get per second (X), then divide the total (T) by X to get Y. The rate is now Y seconds. For each second that passes while you are counting the rate, add the new Y to the previous Y and divide by 2 (average them), that is the new rate (Y seconds). Now you can either store the rate per second or after you've received T items.

If there is previous data, then set the last and new Y to the previously stored rate, then continue with the above method.

Comment: Not sure if I'm following you. So, using my example above, let's say that on the first get I've got 50 items. Since that's my first fetch I need to suppose that I got that in 1 second (just to simplify.. can't use 0, you know, because 0 doesn't like to be in the denominator). If my total is 10, then my new rate should be 10/50. Since I don't want to fetch in intervals less than a second, the second fetch will happen right 1 second after the first one.
So, second fetch, I get 5 items. Now you say that I should use (10/5 + 10/50) / 2?

Comment: If your total is 10 but you get 50 items, you've got a problem.
Yes, count the amount of items you get per second for every second, and then continuously average them.